# unable to print string value using sprintf in c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

i have function that takes two parameters of type LPTSTR, and i am trying print both the values using sprintf like below and i am not able to print the exact values.

```
int __stdcall Logon(LPTSTR UserName, LPTSTR Password)
{
  char Buffer[2048];
  sprintf(Buffer,"UserName: %s\n m_Password: %s\n",UserName,Password);
  FILE *Ls=fopen("lo.log",a);
  fprintf(Ls,Buffer);
  fclose(Ls);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `UserName` and `Password` are stored as wide strings (`wchar_t`) and you are trying to put them into a `char[]` buffer, then visual c++ uses `%S` to accomplish this.

```
sprintf(Buffer,"UserName: %S\n m_Password: %S\n",UserName,Password);
```

Answer (score 4):

Either fix "Use Unicode strings" in you project settings or use the

```
_stprintf(Buffer, _T("UserName: %S\n m_Password: %S\n"), UserName, Password);
```

and

```
#include <tchar.h>
```

If you use Unicode (and you do), use the '%S' format.

Comment: thank you for your quick response but modifying the sprintf this way is just giving me the first characters of the string not the entire string.

Comment: Please, give us the complete code (namely the LPTSTR vars definition - Buffer, UserName, Password)